# Implementing IEnumerable

Tags: linq-to-sql, generics

I am using LINQ and am having a hard time understanding how I can make new "domain model" classes work within LINQ while querying across tables.  I am using Linq to SQL, and C# in .NET 3.5.

Suppose I want an Extended Client class:

```
public class ExtendedClient 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string strVal { get; set; }
}
```

and in my data layer, I want to populate this from two tables (dc is my DataContext):

```
public ExtendedClient getExtendedClient(int clientID)
{
    var c = dc.GetTable<tClient>();
    var cs = dc.GetTable<tClientSetting>();
    var q = from client in c
            join setting in cs
            on client.ClientID equals setting.ClientID
            where client.ClientID == clientID
            select new ExtendedClient { client, setting.strValue };
    return q;   
}
```

I am trying to return the row in the table tClient plus one extra column in tClientSetting.

The annoying errors I get are :
Cannot initialize type 'ExtendedClient' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'
and
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'ExtendedClient'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I realize this is a basic error, but I cannot determine how BEST to implement the IEnumerable because I cannot find an example.

Do I have to do this *every time* I want a specialized object?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public ExtendedClient getExtendedClient(int clientID)
{
    var c = dc.GetTable<tClient>();
    var cs = dc.GetTable<tClientSetting>();
    var q = from client in c
            join setting in cs
            on client.ClientID equals setting.ClientID
            where client.ClientID == clientID
            select new ExtendedClient { ID = client.ClientID, Name = client.Name, strVal = setting.strValue };
    return q.Single();
}
```

You'll have to do a similar thing *every time you need to **return** a specialized object*. If you don't need to return it, you don't have to specify the type and you won't need a special class. You could use anonymous types:

```
from client in c
join setting in cs
on client.ClientID equals setting.ClientID
where client.ClientID == clientID
select new { ID = client.ClientID, Name = client.Name, strVal = setting.strValue };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a special type for this?

I think you can do `client.Settings.strValue` if you setup the Client-Settings relationship to create a property `Client.Settings` (instead of `Settings.Client`). And as far as I remember such configuration is possible in LINQ.